# How can I correct the program which generates random dice rolls

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, module, parse-error

```
def reject():
  print("get out!")
  quit()
import random
print("chooses random dice rolls")
maximumval=int(input("how many dice rolls do you want?"))
if maximumval<0:
   reject()
else:
    counter=1
    while counter<=maximumval:
        counter=str(counter)
        mydict={
      
         }
         
         val=random.randint(1,7)
         val=str(val)
         mydict.update({counter:val})
         val=int(val)
         counter=int(counter)
        counter+=1
    print(mydict)
```

it gives parseError on line 17

I was not able to solve it. It says parseError.

Comment: Your indentation is off.

Comment: What is this mydict={
      
         } It is empty dictionary?

Comment: I can't reproduce your "parseError". With this code I get `IndentationError: unexpected indent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation in python is crucial for code blocks. It seems like you have extra spaces in front of all rows between row `17` ( `val=random.randint(1,7)` ) and `21` ( `counter=int(counter)` ) including both edges. Remove the extra spaces and you should be good to go.

Fixed code:

```py
def reject():
  print("get out!")
  quit()
import random
print("chooses random dice rolls")
maximumval=int(input("how many dice rolls do you want?"))
if maximumval<0:
   reject()
else:
    counter=1
    while counter<=maximumval:
        counter=str(counter)
        mydict={
      
         }
         
        val=random.randint(1,7)
        val=str(val)
        mydict.update({counter:val})
        val=int(val)
        counter=int(counter)
        counter+=1
    print(mydict)
```

Consider using an IDE/Text Editor like vscode with the correct extensions this will help you identify such mistakes.

Comment: If the problem was indentation, then surely the error would have been `IndentationError`, not `parseError` as stated?